# Dictionary of numpy arrays to (transposed) csv

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I've a dictionary of numpy float arrays:

```
labels = 'L0', 'L1', 'L2'
x = {'a': array([1.0, 1.1, 1.2]), 'b':array([2.0, 2.1, 2.2])}
```

I'd like to get a .csv file something like

```
'Label','a', 'b'
'L1',1.0, 2.0
'L2',1.1, 2.1
'L3',1.2, 2.2
```

New to Python ... I'm somewhat lost... Thx. for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) has exactly the thing. You will love it

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(x, index=labels)
dataframe.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Thx., @Marat, perfect. Small addition: `dataframe.index.name = 'Label'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythons [csv-module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for that. You would need to specify `quotechar="'"` and `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to ensure the quoting you wanted:

```
import numpy as np

labels = 'L0', 'L1', 'L2'
x = {'a': np.array([1.0, 1.1, 1.2]), 'b':np.array([2.0, 2.1, 2.2])}

import csv

with open("d.txt","w", newline="") as f:
    # ensure quoting of non numerics
    wr = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    header = ["Label"] + [k for k in x.keys()]
    wr.writerow(header)
    data = zip(labels,*x.values())
    for d in data:
        wr.writerow(d)

print(open("d.txt").read())
```

Output of file:

```
'Label','a','b'
'L0',1.0,2.0
'L1',1.1,2.1
'L2',1.2,2.2
```